# Could not find Django-eel - pyinstaller+django-eel

Tags: python

I'm using the library Django-eel,which is a library i use alongside Django. After using pyinstaller to create a EXE file, the following error pops up when opening the EXE:

```
daphne\server.py:11: UserWarning: Something has already installed a non-asyncio Twisted reactor. Attempting to uninstall it; you can fix this warning by importing daphne.server early in your codebase or finding the package that imports Twisted and importing it later on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "django_eel\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1130, in resource_filename
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 342, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 886, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'django-eel' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[17688] Failed to execute script 'manage' due to unhandled exception!
```

So I tried using hidden-imports and add django-eel but that didn't work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you have any solution on this? i face the same issue also